# Image Manipulation - is this a for-loop issue?

Tags: c++, image, pointers, for-loop

I have an image that I'm trying to blur out, but it ends up looking very weird indeed:

[image]

What I DO is this: I take each pixel, and I average its value on a color-by-color basis with the values of all adjacent pixels.

Or so I think. But there's clearly an error in there, and I suspect there's a problem with my for-loops but for the life of me I cannot find out what is actually going wrong.

In particular, step five (the output step) shows that the image is still ordered - if I output the left image on the right side, rather than the blur-masked image, the pixels are still in the correct order.

```
    try
{
    // STEP ONE: MAKE MEMORY AVAILABLE FOR IMAGE
    int ***image;
    image = new int**[m_nSizeX];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_nSizeX; ++i)
    {
        image[i] = new int*[m_nSizeY];
        for(int j = 0; j < m_nSizeY; ++j)
        {
            image[i][j] = new int[nrPixels];// image[x][y][z] is now a pointer to an int

        }
    }

    // STEP TWO: MAKE MEMORY AVAILABLE FOR IMAGE MASK
    int ***mask;
    mask = new int**[m_nSizeX];
    for(int i = 0; i < m_nSizeX; ++i)
    {
        mask[i] = new int*[m_nSizeY];
        for(int j = 0; j < m_nSizeY; ++j)
        {
            mask[i][j] = new int[nrPixels];// mask[x][y][z] is now a pointer to an int

        }
    }

    //STEP THREE: COPY IMAGE INTO MEMORY

    unsigned long lOffset = 0;
    for(long i=0; i<m_nSizeX ; i++)
    {
        for(long j=0; j<m_nSizeY ; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<(nrPixels) ; k++)
            {
                image[i][j][k] = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pcMemOrg + lOffset) );
                lOffset++;
            }
        }
    }

    // STEP FOUR: BLUR IMAGE

    for(long i=0; i<m_nSizeX ; i++)
    {
        for(long j=0; j<m_nSizeY ; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<(nrPixels) ; k++)
            {
                // INSERT BLURRING FUNCTION HERE (New value = Old value averaged with adjacent pixels)

                if(k != 2) // 0 = blue, 1 = green, 2 = red;
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = 0;
                }
                else


                if(i==0 && j==0)// (0,0) Corner Pixel
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i+1][j][k]+image[i][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j+1][k])/4;
                }
                else if(i==0 && j==(m_nSizeY-1))// (0,yMax) Corner Pixel
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i+1][j][k]+image[i][j-1][k]+image[i+1][j-1][k])/4;
                }
                else if(i==(m_nSizeX-1) && j==0)// (xMax,0) Corner Pixel
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i-1][j][k]+image[i][j+1][k]+image[i-1][j+1][k])/4;
                }
                else if(i==(m_nSizeX-1) && j==(m_nSizeY-1))// (xMax,yMax) Corner Pixel
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i-1][j][k]+image[i][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j-1][k])/4;
                }
                else if(i==0)// (0,---) Edge Pixels
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j][k]+image[i+1][j-1][k]+image[i][j-1][k])/6;
                }
                else if(j==0)// (---,0) Edge Pixels
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i-1][j][k]+image[i-1][j+1][k]+image[i][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j][k])/6;                    
                }
                else if(i==(m_nSizeX-1))// (xMax,---) Edge Pixels
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j][k]+image[i-1][j+1][k]+image[i][j+1][k])/6;
                }
                else if(j==(m_nSizeY-1))// (---,yMax) Edge Pixels
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i+1][j][k]+image[i+1][j-1][k]+image[i][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j][k])/6;
                }
                else // Mid-Image Pixels
                {
                    mask[i][j][k] = (image[i][j][k]+image[i][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j+1][k]+image[i+1][j][k]+image[i+1][j-1][k]+image[i][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j-1][k]+image[i-1][j][k]+image[i-1][j+1][k])/9;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //STEP FIVE: OUTPUT BLURRED IMAGE
    lOffset = 0;

    for(long i=0; i<m_nSizeX ; i++)
    {
        for(long j=0; j<m_nSizeY ; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<(nrPixels) ; k++)
            {
                *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pcMemInv + lOffset) ) = mask[i][j][k];
                //*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pcMemInv + lOffset) ) = image[i][j][k];
                lOffset++;
            }
        }
    }


    // STOP USING IMAGE MEMORY NOW

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nSizeX; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_nSizeY; ++j)
            delete [] image[i][j];

        delete [] image[i];
    }
    delete [] image;

    // STOP USING MASK MEMORY NOW
    for (int i = 0; i < m_nSizeX; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_nSizeY; ++j)
            delete [] mask[i][j];

        delete [] mask[i];
    }
    delete [] mask;
}
catch( ... )
{

}
```

Comment: `int ***image` Egads!  Might I recommend a `std::vector<int>`? And a function that transforms an x,y,z pair into an index in the container?

Comment: I actually did this with vectors first. I've cut render time down by about 45 seconds per frame by going from vectors to direct pointers

Comment: Use _one_ `std::vector<int>`, and initialize it to have `m_nSizeX * m_nSizeY * nrPixels` elements in it.  That would use a single allocation, compared to your many, many thousands of allocations.  Plus, you'll get _far_ better cache locality.  With optimizations enabled, there's no way this could be slower than your code (there are no absolutes when it comes to performance, but I'm willing to go out on a limb here...).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis is right. There will be no difference when you compile a release(optimized) build. Medivh, if you have a debug compile and/or have a debugger attached, performance will be low. Just use a small image while you are debugging.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis is correct if you use the vector that way, but I would be careful about calling a function (or more than one) in each iteration of a tight loop. In image processing (contrary to general guidelines) minimizing function calls is a good thing and usually necessary.

Comment: @EdS.:  I was thinking of a function that simply computes the index, given the x, y, and z values, i.e., a function with a single return statement.  Something that even a braindead optimizing compiler could expand inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multi-dimensional indexing, usually the first index is `y`, the second `x` and the third `red/green/blue` - you use a nonstandard transposed layout with `i`, `j` and `k`, where `i` seems to mean a horizontal index (seeing that you compare it to `m_nSizeX`).

I guess your image is getting transposed when you copy it the first time, transformed in a mysterious way, and transposed back when you copy it the second time; i cannot guess the details, but it's enough to advise you to just get the dimensions right (swap `i` and `j`).

By the way, calling coordinates the normal names `x` and `y` (instead of `i` and `j`, or maybe `j` and `i`?) helps.

Comment: That sounds like it could very well be the answer, judging from an additional test I did after I posted this. I've packed away my gear and am about to head home, but I'll test tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Changing my counting variables to x/y/z and then changing it up so y was before x fixed everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the type of `m_pcMemOrg`, but based on the fact that you need a `reinterpret_cast` I'm guessing it's not `unsigned char`. More importantly I think `sizeof(*m_pcMemOrg)` is not one. Therefore when you add the offset to it, the offset is multiplied by the size of the type.

Replace:

```
image[i][j][k] = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pcMemOrg + lOffset) );
```

with:

```
image[i][j][k] = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_pcMemOrg) + lOffset );
```

And likewise with the output code.

As an aside, the others are correct in pointing out that this is a horribly inefficient way of storing and traversing an image. A one-dimensional array is best, indexed using the equation `[j*stride + i*nrPixels + k]` where `stride = m_nSizeX*nrPixels`. I'd also swap the `i` and `j` loops, and use `x` and `y` as the names instead.